# Java - map a list of objects to a list with values of their property attributes

Tags: java, list, properties

I have the ViewValue class defined as follows:

```
class ViewValue {

private Long id;
private Integer value;
private String description;
private View view;
private Double defaultFeeRate;

// getters and setters for all properties
}
```

Somewhere in my code i need to convert a list of ViewValue instances to a list containing values of id fields from corresponding ViewValue.

I do it using foreach loop:

```
List<Long> toIdsList(List<ViewValue> viewValues) {

   List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();

   for (ViewValue viewValue : viewValues) {
      ids.add(viewValue.getId());
   }

   return ids;
```

}

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

EDIT: This answer is based on the idea that you'll need to do similar things for different entities and different properties elsewhere in your code. If you *only* need to convert the list of ViewValues to a list of Longs by ID, then stick with your original code. If you want a more reusable solution, however, read on...

I would declare an interface for the projection, e.g.

```
public interface Function<Arg,Result>
{
    public Result apply(Arg arg);
}
```

Then you can write a single generic conversion method:

```
public <Source, Result> List<Result> convertAll(List<Source> source,
    Function<Source, Result> projection)
{
    ArrayList<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    for (Source element : source)
    {
         results.add(projection.apply(element));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Then you can define simple projections like this:

```
private static final Function<ViewValue, Long> ID_PROJECTION =
    new Function<ViewValue, Long>()
    {
        public Long apply(ViewValue x)
        {
            return x.getId();
        }
    };
```

And apply it just like this:

```
List<Long> ids = convertAll(values, ID_PROJECTION);
```

(Obviously using K&R bracing and longer lines makes the projection declaration a bit shorter :)

Frankly all of this would be a lot nicer with lambda expressions, but never mind...

Comment: Very Javaesque solution  - but not in a good way. It doesnt exactly reduce the amount or complexity of the code, does it?

Comment: I'd say it's more LINQ-esque than Java-esque personally. I'd rather create the conversion code and then isolate the projection aspect, but if you'd rather duplicate the conversion logic loads of times, that's fine. It would be a lot nicer with lambda expressions, of course.

Comment: Does it not something like we do with Comparator in Java?

Comment: Not really - that only converts to int from what I remember. However, I approached this with the idea of reuse which may not be required - editing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: (Note that my "loads of times" comment was assuming this would be required for different properties etc as well, rather than just the one.)

Comment: You really don't need the ID_PROJECTION field. Creating it each time would give shorter code, in a better order, that probably ran faster.

Comment: It depends on how many places it's going to be used. If it's only going to be used in one place I'd probably put it inline. For more than one, I'd rather just specify it once.

Answer (score 63):

We can do it in a single line of code using java 8

```
List<Long> ids = viewValues.stream().map(ViewValue::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For more info : **[Java 8 - Streams](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm)**

Comment: Fortunately we are getting the things simplified as we are developing:)

Comment: Ok let me put it straight: I would add comments, that this is enabled with Java8 which wasn't available at the time of writing. The answer is actually a large step forward to what has been written 7 years ago.

Comment: You're just awesome with this answer.

Answer (score 33):

You could do it in a one-liner using Commons BeanUtils and Collections:
*(why write your own code when others have done it for you?)*

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanToPropertyValueTransformer;
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;

...

List<Long> ids = (List<Long>) CollectionUtils.collect(viewValues, 
                                       new BeanToPropertyValueTransformer("id"));
```

Comment: +1 for the comment "why write your own code when others have done it for you?" This is an issue we face on a daily basis - having to create a solution to a problem that has already been solved.

Comment: PropertyUtils.getProperty(object, propertyName); uses reflection under the hood which would have an extra performance cost. For that I would use instead Jon Skeet's approach.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is the lack of type safety - if the `viewValue.id` field was renamed, the code would still compile but fail at runtime.

Answer (score 32):

Use google collections. Example:

```
    Function<ViewValue, Long> transform = new Function<ViewValue, Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long apply(ViewValue from) {
            return from.getId();
        }
    };
    List<ViewValue> list = Lists.newArrayList();
    List<Long> idsList = Lists.transform(list, transform);
```

**UPDATE:**

On Java 8 you don't need Guava. You can:

```
import com.example.ViewValue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

Function<ViewValue, Long> transform = ViewValue::getId;
List<ViewValue> source = new ArrayList<>();
List<Long> result = source.stream().map(transform).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or just:

```
List<ViewValue> source= new ArrayList<>();
List<Long> result = source.stream().map(ViewValue::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**NEXT UPDATE (The last one after Javaslang to Vavr name change):**

Currently it's worth to mention about the solution with <strike>Javaslang library(http://www.javaslang.io/)</strike> Vavr library (http://www.vavr.io/). Let's assume that we have our list with genuine objects:

```
List<ViewValue> source = newArrayList(new ViewValue(1), new ViewValue(2), new ViewValue(2));
```

We could make transformation with List class from Javaslang library (on the long run the collect is not convenient):

```
List<Long> result = io.vavr.collection.List.ofAll(source).map(ViewValue::getId).toJavaList();
```

But you will see the power with only the Javaslang lists:

```
io.vavr.collection.List<ViewValue> source = javaslang.collection.List.of(new ViewValue(1), new ViewValue(2), new ViewValue(3));
io.vavr.collection.List<Long> res = source.map(ViewValue::getId);
```

I encourage to take a look available collections and new types on that library (I like especially the Try type). You will find the documentation under the following address: <strike>http://www.javaslang.io/javaslang-docs/</strike> http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/.

PS. Due to the Oracle and the "Java" word within the name they had to change the library name from javaslang to something else. They had decided to Vavr.

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented a small functional library for this usecase. One of the methods has this signature:

```
<T> List<T> mapToProperty(List<?> objectList, String property, Class<T> returnType)
```

Which takes the string and uses reflection to create a call to the property then it returns a List backed by the objectList where get and iterator implemented using this property call.

The mapToProperty functions is implemented in terms of a general map function that takes a Function as a mapper though, just as another post described. Very usefull.

I suggest you read up on basic functionl programming and in particular take a look at Functors (objects implementing a map function)

Edit: Reflection really doesn't have to be expensive. The JVM has improved a lot in this area. Just make sure to compile the invocation once and reuse it.

Edit2: Sample code

```
public class MapExample {
    public static interface Function<A,R>
    {
        public R apply(A b);
    }

    public static <A,R> Function<A,R> compilePropertyMapper(Class<A> objectType, String property, Class<R> propertyType)
    {
        try {
            final Method m = objectType.getMethod("get" + property.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + property.substring(1));

            if(!propertyType.isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType()))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Property "+property+" on class "+objectType.getSimpleName()+" is not a "+propertyType.getSimpleName()
                );

            return new Function<A,R>() 
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public R apply(A b)
                {
                    try {
                        return (R)m.invoke(b);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                };
            };

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static <T1,T2> List<T2> map(final List<T1> list, final Function<T1,T2> mapper)
    {
        return new AbstractList<T2>()
        {
            @Override
            public T2 get(int index) {
                return mapper.apply(list.get(index));
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return list.size();
            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T1,T2> List<T2> mapToProperty(List<T1> list, String property, Class<T2> propertyType)
    {
        if(list == null)
            return null;
        else if(list.isEmpty())
            return Collections.emptyList();

        return map(list,compilePropertyMapper((Class<T1>)list.get(0).getClass(), property, propertyType));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a wrapper:

```
public class IdList impements List<Long>
{
    private List<ViewValue> underlying;

    pubic IdList(List<ViewValue> underying)
    {
        this.underlying = underying;
    }

    public Long get(int index)
    {
        return underlying.get(index).getId()
    }

    // other List methods
}
```

Though that's even more tedious work, it could improve performance.

You could also implement your and my solution generic-ly using reflection, but that would be very bad for performance.

There's no short and easy generic solution in Java, I'm afraid. In Groovy, you would simply use collect(), but I believe that involves reflection as well.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you then do with the `List<Long>`, and the `List<ViewValue>`

For example you might get sufficient functionality from creating your own List implementation that wraps a `List<ViewValue>`, implementing `iterator()` with an iterator implementation that iterates over the ViewValues, returning the id.

Answer (score 2):

You can populate a map from the properties of a list of objects (say id as key and some property as value) as below

```
Map<String, Integer> mapCount = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::get_id, Object::proprty));
```