# How to make a new list with a property of an object which is in another list

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream, guava

Imagine that I have a list of certain objects:

```
List<Student>
```

And I need to generate another list including the `ids` of `Students` in the above list:

```
List<Integer>
```

Avoiding using a loop, is it possible to achieve this by using **apache collections** or **guava**?

***Which methods should be useful for my case?***

Comment: Hey, I found it just now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737244/java-map-a-list-of-objects-to-a-list-with-values-of-their-property-attributes

Comment: Jon's answer is pretty cool but if you look at it, it also uses a loop. Any any solution will use a loop - although it might not be visible to you, but internally it will

Comment: someone has to apply loop to get it done. either you or some lib that you may use.

Comment: Actually jon's answer does not fit my situation in that i do not wanna use for loop. I think there is a more convenient way over somewhere but waitin for me to find it:)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Java 8 way of doing it:-

```
List<Integer> idList = students.stream().map(Student::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What if I want a list of tuples? Something like [(Id, name),(Id, name)].

Comment: Not all 1.8 features are supported for all Android APIs. In particular, java.util.stream is not supported until API 24.

Answer (score 42):

With Guava you can use Function like -

```
private enum StudentToId implements Function<Student, Integer> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public Integer apply(Student input) {
            return input.getId();
        }
    }
```

and you can use this function to convert List of students to ids like -

```
Lists.transform(studentList, StudentToId.INSTANCE);
```

Surely it will loop in order to extract all ids, but remember guava methods returns view and Function will only be applied when you try to iterate over the `List<Integer>` 
 
If you don't iterate, it will never apply the loop. 

*Note: Remember this is the view and if you want to iterate multiple times it will be better to copy the content in some other `List<Integer>` like*

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.transform(students, StudentToId.INSTANCE));
```

Comment: I think it's inelegant to have to define a function separately. I think this can also be done anonymously and in a one step process

Comment: how do you extract string ( float,etc) members of the List?

Answer (score 22):

Thanks to **Premraj** for the alternative cool option, upvoted.

I have used apache CollectionUtils and BeanUtils. Accordingly, I am satisfied with performance of the following code:

```
List<Long> idList = (List<Long>) CollectionUtils.collect(objectList, 
                                    new BeanToPropertyValueTransformer("id"));
```

It is worth mentioning that, I will compare the performance of guava (**Premraj** provided) and collectionUtils I used above, and decide the faster one.

Comment: I will prefer Guava over apache collections irrespective of performance for reasons like - more modern, generics, doesn't use reflection for transformations etc. Overall guava is far more modern that apache collections - read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444437/apache-commons-vs-guava-formerly-google-collections)

Comment: Yes, but actually it does not seem a good idea to me to restrict the usage of it by a compulsory need of extra enum declaration for each type of object I want to transform.

Comment: Well it depends on your design - You can have interface say `Identifiable` which defines `getId()` method and then you can use this single enum singleton pattern to extract Id commonly.

Comment: guava is definitely more efficient than Bean utils as the later uses reflections..

Comment: Using the property name as a String in the constructor new BeanToPropertyValueTransformer("id") is something I definitely try to avoid. Refactoring gonna be hard! But I'm looking for a solution to workaround this. Meanwhile, I will go with the Guava solution, verbose but safe.

Answer (score 10):

Java 8 lambda expression solution:

```
List<Integer> iDList = students.stream().map((student) -> student.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If Java < 1.8 then use Apache CollectionUtils. Example: Collection<String> firstnames = CollectionUtils.collect(userlist, TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getFirstname"));

Answer (score 6):

If someone get here after a few years:

```
List<String> stringProperty = (List<String>) CollectionUtils.collect(listOfBeans, TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getProperty"));
```

Comment: And you just saved me :)

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30130428) can be written in a further shorter form in [JDK 16 which includes a toList() method directly on Stream instances](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8180352).

## Java 16 solution

```
List<Integer> idList = students.stream().map(Student::getId).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) for this purpose

```
Student first = new Student(1);
Student second = new Student(2);
Student third = new Student(3);

MutableList<Student> list = Lists.mutable.of(first, second, third);
List<Integer> result = list.collect(Student::getId);

System.out.println(result); // [1, 2, 3]
```