# Convert ArrayList(Hashmap<String,String>) to some Arraylists

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have an `ArrayList(Hashmap<String, String>)` named users and each `Hashmap<String, String>` contains the profile of a user such as `name`,`id`,`phone`, etc...

I want to convert this `ArrayList` into some simple `ArrayList`. For example, I want to have an id `ArrayLis`t that contains all ids that can be found in the main `ArrayList`. Is there any function to do that?

Comment: add an exemple of data, because it's not clear what are asking for, add what you did so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - map a list of objects to a list with values of their property attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737244/java-map-a-list-of-objects-to-a-list-with-values-of-their-property-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write such a function with `Stream`s:

```
public static List<String> getPropertyList(List<Map<String,String>> users, String key)
{
    return users.stream()
                .map(m -> m.get(key))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then call it with:

```
List<String> userIds = getPropertyList(users,"id");
List<String> userNames = getPropertyList(users,"name");
...
```

P.S. I changed the type of the list from `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` to `List<Map<String,String>>`, since it's better to program to interfaces.

If you are using Java 7 or older, you'll need a loop:

```
public static List<String> getPropertyList(List<Map<String,String>> users, String key)
{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map<String,String> map : users) {
        result.add(map.get(key));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man but it seems this code requires 1.8 version of java, can you edit that part that requires java1.8?

Comment: the line is 'm -> m.get(key)'

Comment: @ShakibKarami ok, I just did