# Java 8 Generalised way map a collection of objects for a given property passed as string

Tags: java, generics, reflection, collections, java-8

I was reviewing this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/737244/495157) and specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/737244/495157) answer.

```
List<Long> ids = viewValues.stream().map(ViewValue::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I was wondering if this can somehow be adapted to make a generalized utility method,
but I am stuck on the syntax for the `map` part and using some sort of Reflection to get the getter name via a String.

Can someone give me some pointers as to whether this is feasible, and how to fix this code?

```
public static List<String> getStringListOfCollectionProperty(List<T> l, String propName) {
        return l.stream().map(T::propName).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am not allowed to use 3rd party libraries like Guava etc.

Comment: Because I want to return a list of names. But other times maybe a list of descriptions etc.. Depends on what properties are in the collection l

Comment: in such case, just let users specify a `Function` of how they want to achieve that, no?

Comment: @Eugene. Can you elaborate? I don't understand.

Comment: there is already an answer with what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the caller do the mapping by sending in a function (just as `map()` does):

```
public static <T> List<String> getStringListOfCollectionProperty(List<T> l, 
      Function<T, String> propMapper) {
        return l.stream().map(propMapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: So how would I invoke that? What goes in the function argument in the caller?

Comment: @JGFMK `List<String> result = getStringListOfCollectionProperty(viewValues, ViewValue::getId);`, for example

Comment: Have been Googling.. I think this is it.. `Function<ExtendedCalendar, String> f = ec -> ec.name;`
  `List<String> extCal = getListOfTypeUForCollectionTsProperty(this.extendedCalendars, f);`

Comment: Yep. Just tested. And it worked treat. Thanks. Never used Function in Java before. Seen similar stuff in TypeScript/JavaScript/Python. Just never done that in Java before. Cool ;-) (Sourced it from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-interface-in-java-with-examples/)